# (Google Foobar XOR Checksum Challenge) How do i optimize this function to run for much larger values?

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, mathematics, bitwise

I wrote a function that accepts 2 integers start and length as input and returns the bitwise XOR of certain numbers as described below:

```
if start = 0 and length = 4, the process would look like:
0 1 2 3 /
4 5 6 / 7
8 9 / 10 11
12 / 13 14 15 16
which produces the checksum 0^1^2^3^4^5^6^8^9^12 == 10
```

My code works well enough for lengths below 10000, but just hangs when the length is say 44000. How do I optimize the solution?

```
def solution(start,length):
    if length == 1:
        return start
    result = start ^ (start+1)
    iter = 0
    var = start + 1
    offset = 1
    while iter < (length + length**2)/2 - 2:
        if (var-start)%(length-1) == 0:
            var += offset
            result ^= var
            offset += 1
            iter += 1
            continue
        var += 1
        result ^= var
        iter += 1
    return result
```

Comment: See the answers here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/153262/35991 for an much more efficient approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import xor

def optimized_solution(start, length):
    result = 0 
    for i in range(length, 0, -1):
        result = reduce(xor, range(start, start+i), result)
        start += length
    return result
```

For `optimized_solution(0, 4)`:

```
i -> 4, 3, 2, 1
```

For first iteration you create a `range` object from `0` to `0+4`, and perform the `xor`, with `result` as initial value, provided as the third argument in the `reduce` function.

```
result = reduce(xor, range(0, 4), 0) # result_after_iteration_1
```

And then you increase `start` by `length` amount.

In the next iteration, `i` becomes `3`, `result` becomes:

```
result = reduce(xor, range(4, 8), result_after_iteration_1) # result_after_iteration_2
```

And so on....

```
def optimized_solution(start, length):
    result = 0 
    for i in range(length, 0, -1): # 4, 3, 2, 1
        # for 1st iteration:
        # xor of range(0, 0+4) => 0 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 3
        result = reduce(xor, range(start, start+i), result)
        # new start = 0 + 4 = 4
        start += length
    return result
```

Output:

```
>>> optimized_solution(0, 4)
10
>>> optimized_solution(1, 1)
1
```

Performance:

```
>>> %timeit solution(0, 1000)  # solution func as given in the question
364 ms ± 29.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> %timeit optimized_solution(0, 1000)
31.5 ms ± 1.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If you are not allowed to import [`operator.xor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.xor) or [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), a roughly equivalent version to the above solution would be:

```
def optimized_solution(start, length):
    result = 0 
    for i in range(length, 0, -1):
        for j in range(start, start+i):
            result ^= j
        start += length
    return result
```

Performance of the above solution:

```
>>> %timeit optimized_solution(0, 1000)
41.7 ms ± 5.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: @KellyBundy added performance for the last solution. And about linear time, still trying to figure out a formula for `xor of n to n+m`

Comment: @SayandipDutta You're on the right path, `xor of n to n+m` can be done in constant time.